# Which DNS entries need to be updated when moving email from one service to another?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, mx

So, I'm keeping my website with my registrar and moving the email to a better service (better than the awful cPanel one).

I'm giving myself a crash course in A, AAAA, CNAME MX SRV TXT.
Which records do I update?  Is it just MX and TXT, or more?

I'm aiming for a seamless transition from one to the other.

Comment: Does your new provider offer webmail or a web control panel where users can do things like change their email password?

Comment: I am curious why you think the cPanel email service is "awful".  Cpanel is nothing more than a front end for the underlying operating system.

Comment: It's just that my server is parked on a network that must have sent a lot of spam.  My emails to hotmail/live/comcast are bounced back to me.  It's like whenever I send an email I have no clue whether it'll arrive or not.

Comment: OK, that is mail server reputation and it has nothing to do with cpanel or even the quality of your mail server. If that is what is going on, suggesting cpanel is awful or is even part of the problem is completely wrong.

Comment: Please pass on my apologies to cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Create an MX record pointing to `mail.example.com` and then an A record pointing `mail.example.com` to the IP address of the mail server.  By default this is usually the same as the A record for the domain.

Of course there are other ways of using a different mail service. One example is to create an email forwarder for `you@example.com` to Gmail and then in Gmail settings you can set it up to send from `you@example.com`